# preg_replace_callback with Spoilers into Spoilers

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

i write something like `[spoiler=Spoiler Title]text inside the Spoiler[/spoiler]`
and use `preg_replace_callback("/\[spoiler=(.*)\](.*)\[\/spoiler\]/Usi", 'BBCode_spoiler', $text);` to create a real spoiler, the result with one or more spoiler is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show_0() {
        if(document.getElementById("0").style.display == "inline-block")
            document.getElementById("0").style.display = "none";
        else document.getElementById("0").style.display = "inline-block"; }
</script>
<a href="javascript:show_0();"><i>Show Spiler:</i> <b>Spoiler Title</a></b><br>
<div id="0" style="display: none; min-width: 100px; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #000000;">
    Text inside the Spoiler
</div>
```

how do i make it works with a spoiler into a spoiler
like `[spoiler=Spoiler Title][spoiler=Second Spoiler]Another Text[/spoiler][/spoiler]`
my current function returns by none spoiler into a spoiler

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show_0() {
        if(document.getElementById("0").style.display == "inline-block")
            document.getElementById("0").style.display = "none";
        else document.getElementById("0").style.display = "inline-block"; }
</script>
<a href="javascript:show_0();"><i>Show Spiler:</i> <b>Spoiler Title</a></b><br>
<div id="0" style="display: none; min-width: 100px; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #000000;">
    [spoiler=Second&nbsp;Spoiler]Another Text</div>[/spoiler]
```

my callback function is

```
<?php
// Spoiler
$counter = 0;
function BBCode_spoiler($hits) {
    global $central_lang;
    global $counter;
    $title = htmlentities(trim($hits[1]));
    $text = htmlentities($hits[2]);
    $return = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
    $return .= "function show_".$counter."() {";
    $return .= "if(document.getElementById(\"".$counter."\").style.display == \"inline-block\") document.getElementById(\"".$counter."\").style.display = \"none\";";
    $return .= "else document.getElementById(\"".$counter."\").style.display = \"inline-block\"; }";
    $return .= "</script>";
    $return .= "<a href=\"javascript:show_".$counter."();\"><i>".$central_lang['bbcodes']['spoiler']['text'].":</i> <b>".$title."</a></b><br>";
    $return .= "<div id=\"".$counter."\" style=\"display: none; min-width: 100px; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #000000;\">".$text."</div>";
    $counter++;
    return $return; }
?>
```

the output i try to make seems like that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show_0() {
        if(document.getElementById("0").style.display == "inline-block")
            document.getElementById("0").style.display = "none";
        else document.getElementById("0").style.display = "inline-block"; }
</script>
<a href="javascript:show_0();"><i>Show Spoiler:</i> <b>Spoiler Title</a></b><br>
<div id="0" style="display: none; min-width: 100px; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #000000;">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function show_1() {
            if(document.getElementById("1").style.display == "inline-block")
                document.getElementById("1").style.display = "none";
            else document.getElementById("1").style.display = "inline-block"; }
    </script>
    <a href="javascript:show_1();"><i>Show Spoiler:</i> <b>Second Spoiler</a></b><br>
    <div id="1" style="display: none; min-width: 100px; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #000000;">
        Another text
    </div>
</div>
```

i hope it's there is an answer for my question, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This applies to BBCode in general: re-run the replacement code until it stops changing it.

`preg_replace_callback` accepts a "count" reference variable, which will be filled with the number of replacements made. So long as this number is not zero, you should re-run the replacement (`do..while` is perfect for this)

It doesn't matter that they're crossed over. Let's say we have a BBCode that replaces `[div]` with `<div>`...

```
[div]Blah[div]123[/div]Fish[/div]
```

After one replacement:

```
<div>Blah[div]123</div>Fish[/div]
```

After another replacement:

```
<div>Blah<div>123</div>Fish</div>
```

So even though they were processed in a crossed-over order, the result is properly nested.

Comment: Thank you, i finally made it! I changed my pattern to `/\[spoiler=(.*)\](.*)/Usi` and added `$text = str_replace("[/spoiler]", "</div>", $text);` after my preg_replace_callback function... i made it without `$counter` but it works as well! Thank you

Comment: The problem with that, Alex, is that what if I type `[/spoiler]` with no opening tag? Your site's structure will collapse!

Comment: *it just can change `[/spoiler]` if `$counter` is bigger than 0 ;)

Comment: `[spoiler=Test][/spoiler][/spoiler]`, effect?

Comment: it will, but just one time

Answer (score 0):

You can use the count parameter of preg_replace_callback to process the replacement from innermost to outermost until there is no more tags to replace:

```
$pattern = '~\[spoiler=([^]]*)]((?>[^[]+|\[(?!/?spoiler\b))*)\[/spoiler]~i';

do {
    $result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'BBCode_spoiler', $text, -1, $count);
} while ($count>0);
```

I change a little the pattern to ensure that the match is the innermost tag.